# Is there a way to show tabs and spaces in Codemirror?

Tags: joomla-3.x, editor

I can't see whether the gaps at the beginning of new lines in Codemirror (in Joomla, in my case) are spaces or tabs.

Is there a way to display them?

Answer (score 1):

Tabs can be styled in CSS using `.cm-tab` selector. See demo https://codemirror.net/demo/visibletabs.html.

For other invisibles, you could use CodeMirror Show Invisibles addon https://github.com/coderaiser/cm-show-invisibles. It can be integrated into Joomla! using a plugin which loads the script during `onCodeMirrorBeforeDisplay` event:

```
defined('_JEXEC') or exit;

use Joomla\CMS\HTML\HTMLHelper;
use Joomla\CMS\Plugin\CMSPlugin;

class PlgEditors_CodemirrorShowinvisibles extends CMSPlugin
{
    public function onCodeMirrorBeforeDisplay($displayData)
    {
        // Load the addon script.
        HTMLHelper::_('script', 'plg_editors_codemirror_showinvisibles/show-invisibles.js', ['relative' => true]);

        // Set the flag for showing invisibles.
        $displayData->options->showInvisibles = true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are only differentiating between spaces and tabs, the most instant solution is probably to use your browser's Find tool.  On Chrome, this is Ctrl+F.  Type a space into the search box.  If the targeted whitespace character does not receive the yellow highlight, then it is a tab.  Try the technique here: https://3v4l.org/MIF6B

Also at your disposal is the Inspect dev tool, this is Ctrl+Shft+I.  Access the text in the element of the inspector and highlight the whitespace by click-dragging over it.  If it jumps more than one space, it's a tab.

Another way is to copy all of your raw text, paste it into regex101.com, then write `\t` into the pattern field.  It will highlight all of the tabs in the text.

I am sure that there are more ways to do this, but these seem pretty easy to me.

Comment: Thanks, but I'd much rather be able to use something like regex101.com's `\t` within Codemirror rather than copying code back and forth or highlighting individual spaces/tabs with the browser's inspector. However, looking at Codemirror's github it seems that this option has been rejected some years ago. They mention styling spaces with CSS. I will look at that.